# How to update data of an excel sheet in a userform with vba

Tags: vba, excel

U would like to know how i can retrieve data from an excel sheet and update it in a userform.

on the picture you can see what the userform looks like.
What i would like to do is make another userform that can search for a specific reference in the sheet and update some cells of that specific row.

[image: Userform]
This is the code I have now to insert data into the sheet.

```
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
' Clear the form
 For Each ctl In Me.Controls
 If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
 ctl.Value = ""
 ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
 ctl.Value = False
 End If
 Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
' Check user input

    If Me.combTechnieker.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Dag vreemdeling! Welke van de 4 Mongolen ben je?", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.combTechnieker.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtPcwRef.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul onze referentie in!", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtPcwRef.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtKlant.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul de naam van de klant in!", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtKlant.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtMerk.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul het merk in!", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtMerk.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtMerkRef.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul de referentie van de fabrikant in!", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtMerkRef.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtProduct.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul het product in!", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtProduct.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtSerienummer.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul het serienummer in!", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtSerienummer.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtProbleem.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul de probleem omschrijving in!", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtProbleem.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtOnderdelen.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Bent u zeker dat er geen onderdelen achterblijven. Indien ja. Vul N/A in", vbExclamation, "RMA invoer"
        Me.txtOnderdelen.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

' Write data to worksheet
    RowCount = Worksheets("RMA 2016").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Worksheets("RMA 2016").Range("A1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
        .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = "Open"
        .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.txtPcwRef.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.txtKlant.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.txtMerk.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.txtMerkRef.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.txtProduct.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.txtSerienummer.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.txtOnderdelen.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 10).Value = Me.txtProbleem.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 13).Value = Me.combTechnieker.Value

    If Me.chkGarantie.Value = True Then
     .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = "Ja"
     Else
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = "Nee"
    End If
    End With
    ' Clear the form
     For Each ctl In Me.Controls
     If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
     ctl.Value = ""
    ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
    ctl.Value = False
    End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the question ? where are you getting an error ?

Comment: i now have a user form to insert data into an excel sheet and I now want to make a second userform that can retrieve a specific row of that sheet. so lets say that i have a sheet wit a reference number, then i want to be able to search for that number and update some of the cells of that row where the reference is in

Comment: It's the reverse process. You have to have the button find the `reference_number` in your short and populate text boxes (or whatever) on the user_form ... so you can then make changes and write back to the sheet. As written this question is too broad to receive any real help. Come back with code you have tried to accomplish this and where it's not working, if that is the case.

Comment: Set myRange = Worksheets("RMA 2016").Range("D3:D20000")
    
    Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.txtPcwRef.Value, myRange, 0), 12) = Me.txtDatumTerug.Value

Comment: i have now something as this. where i serch for the value or txtpcwRef and update cell 12 with the value of txtDatumTerug but it doesn't work any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a small example to showcase how the general mechanics of loading, saving and deleting a record can work together with the form. When you try to save a record with non-existing ID, it will append a new record to the table. This should be very close to what you are asking and shows you how to shuffle data between a user form and a worksheet.

[image: Sample table and form]

```
Private Sub cmdLoad_Click()

    ' check if provided product ID is not empty
    If Len(Trim(Me.txtId)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Enter product ID to load the record."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' try to retrieve the product by ID
    Dim rngIdList As Range, rngId As Range
    Set rngIdList = ActiveSheet.Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown))

    Set rngId = rngIdList.Find(Me.txtId, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rngId Is Nothing Then
        ' product ID is not found
        MsgBox "Product ID " & Me.txtId & " doesn't exist."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' product ID is found -- fill out the form
        Me.txtId = rngId.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.txtName = rngId.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.txtNote = rngId.Offset(0, 2)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    ' check if provided product ID is not empty
    If Len(Trim(Me.txtId)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Enter product ID to load the record."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' try to retrieve the product by ID
    Dim rngIdList As Range, rngId As Range
    Set rngIdList = ActiveSheet.Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown))

    Set rngId = rngIdList.Find(Me.txtId, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rngId Is Nothing Then
        ' if product ID is not found, append new one to the end of the table
        With rngIdList
            Set rngId = .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1)
        End With
    End If

    ' update excel record
    rngId.Offset(0, 0) = Me.txtId
    rngId.Offset(0, 1) = Me.txtName
    rngId.Offset(0, 2) = Me.txtNote

End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()

    ' check if provided product ID is not empty
    If Len(Trim(Me.txtId)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Enter product ID to delete the record."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' try to retrieve the product by ID
    Dim rngIdList As Range, rngId As Range
    Set rngIdList = ActiveSheet.Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown))

    Set rngId = rngIdList.Find(Me.txtId, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rngId Is Nothing Then
        ' product ID is not found -- nothing to delete
        MsgBox "Product ID " & Me.txtId & " doesn't exist."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' product ID is found -- delete the entire line
        rngId.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that will explain how to do this.

http://www.onlinepclearning.com/edit-and-delete-from-a-userform/

You essentially need to record a macro using an advanced filter that filters your data based on whatever criteria you want. That data can then be used to feed a listbox in your userform using a dynamic name range where your filtered data is copied too. You can then write some code that allows it feed empty text boxes in the userform when double clicked. Then using a recorded macro that utilizes the 'find' function of excel it can find the updated entry (if it has a unique ID) and replace the old values with the new ones.

The link provided will walk through this step by step. You will just need to modify to fit in your workbook.

Hope this helps!

Example of a project I did:

```
'this is my recorded filter

Sub FilterData()
'
' FilterData Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Propert Data").Range("A6:M80").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("Sheet2!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range( _
        "Sheet2!Extract"), Unique:=False
End Sub

'This feeds the listbox

Dim ws As Worksheet
'Set Worksheet Variable
Set ws = Sheet2
'Run Filter
FilterLoans 'this is a recorded macro
'Add named range to rowsource
If ws.Range("A5").Value = "" Then
Me.loanlist.RowSource = ""
Else
Me.loanlist.RowSource = "FilterLoans" 'this is a dynamic name range
End If

   'This feeds the empty cells

   Private Sub loanlist_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next
i = Me.loanlist.ListIndex
Me.edloannametxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(0, i)
Me.edpropnametxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(1, i)
Me.edloantypecbx.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(2, i)
Me.edbalancetxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(3, i)
Me.edbalancetxt.Value = Format(Val(edbalancetxt.Value), "$#,###")
Me.edpmttxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(4, i)
Me.edpmttxt.Value = Format(Val(edpmttxt.Value), "$#,###")
Me.edannualtxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(5, i)
Me.edannualtxt.Value = Format(Val(edannualtxt.Value), "$#,###")
Me.edratetxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(6, i)
Me.edratetxt.Value = Format(Val(edratetxt.Value), "Percent")
Me.edamtxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(7, i)
Me.edbbtcbx.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(8, i)
Me.uidtxt.Value = Me.loanlist.Column(9, i)

End Sub

'this finds and updates that old data

Private Sub updateloancmd_Click()

Dim findvalue As Range
Dim cNum As Integer
Dim DataSH As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set DataSH = Sheet10

Set findvalue = DataSH.Range("K:K"). _
Find(What:=Me.uidtxt.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

findvalue = uidtxt.Value
If findvalue = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else
findvalue.Offset(0, -1) = edbbtcbx.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, -2) = edamtxt.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, -3) = edratetxt.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, -5) = edpmttxt.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, -6) = edbalancetxt.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, -7) = edloantypecbx.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, -8) = edpropnametxt.Value
findvalue.Offset(0, -9) = edloannametxt.Value
End If

End Sub
```