# Add ComboBox in an Interactive UserForm in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, combobox, userform

I am using this tutorial (https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/interactive-userform.html) for how to create an Interactive Userform that overwrites values based on a simple condition that if ID exists, then update or edit the rows.

However, this works very well for TextBox but I am struggling to add other controls from the Toolbox. Currently, I am trying to add ComboBox in the loops such that it can add values from the ComboBox.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
EditAdd
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ClearForm
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
GetData
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
TextBox1.SetFocus
    ComboBox1.AddItem "One"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Two"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Three"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Four"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Five"
End Sub
```

Here is the module. I've tried to modify it by adding `UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value` in the `for` loops, but I only get errors.

```
Dim id As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

Sub GetData()

If IsNumeric(UserForm.TextBox1.Value) Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm.TextBox1.Value

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 6
                UserForm.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
                UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            Next j
        End If


        i = i + 1

    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 2 To 6
            UserForm.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
            UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j).Value = ""
        Next j
    End If

Else
    ClearForm
End If

End Sub

Sub ClearForm()

For j = 1 To 6
    UserForm.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
    UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j).Value = ""
Next j

End Sub

Sub EditAdd()

Dim emptyRow As Long

If UserForm.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm.TextBox1.Value
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 6
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = UserForm.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j).Value
            Next j
        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 1 To 6
            Cells(emptyRow, j).Value = UserForm.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
            Cells(emptyRow, j).Value = UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j).Value
        Next j
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

How can I add ComboBox into my module such that the Userform overwrites existing values if ID exists?

Comment: What errors? Your code doesn't include any references to comboboxes. Do you have comboxes 2-5?

Comment: @SJR I just updated the code. I get the error `Could not find the specified object.`

Comment: I think the error is fairly self-explanatory, no? Check the names of your comboboxes, your post refers to only one.

Comment: I am new to VBA. I only have one ComboBox in my userform, I don't understand why I need comboboxes 2-5?

Comment: You don't, but you have put them in a loop whose variable runs from 2 to 6.

Comment: Could you please tell me where? I have been looking at this problem for 3 days now.

Comment: `UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j)` - `j` runs from 2 to 6 so you need to take that line out of the loop and just refer to combobox1. I'm not entirely sure what you're doing but looks like you need to duplicate the textbox check for the CB.

Comment: I don't undestand... I do not have that exact line (- `j`). Are you referring to all of the lines that have `UserForm.Controls("ComboBox" & j)`?

Comment: Ignore the hyphen, I was just using that to link the two phrases, but in answer to your question, yes.

Comment: I have tried taking them out and under `End If` but still getting error "Object required" with `Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = ComboBox1.Value` . Are you able to print out exactly what is needed in an answer? I am still struggling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't provide a full answer because I don't understand enough about what you are trying to achieve - hence the various comments and queries in the code. Perhaps it gives you enough to work out what you have to do.

```
Dim id As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

Sub GetData()

If IsNumeric(UserForm.TextBox1.Value) Then 'separate check required for combobox?
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm.TextBox1.Value

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""
        If UserForm.ComboBox1.Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value Then 'not sure if this check is right and the j needs to be replaced with something
            'do something
            'should this be a separate flag?
        End If
        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 6
                UserForm.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            Next j
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If flag = False Then 'might need changing if separate flags required
        UserForm.ComboBox1.Value = ""
        For j = 2 To 6
            UserForm.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
        Next j
    End If

Else
    ClearForm
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. I found a simpler solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336721/how-to-update-data-of-an-excel-sheet-in-a-userform-with-vba. I'll accept yours for trying to help me :)