# Delete Data from VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

So currently i'm working on VBA forms(Product Master) , and got stuck across this problem. So basically, i have 3 buttons for my data i.e., Add, Update and Delete. Done with Add and Update button.
Just don't know how to delete my data from listbox which is in userform, and this user form is connected to a worksheet.

'''

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub btn_ProductMaster_Add_Click()



If Me.txt_Product_Name.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Product Name", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNumeric(Me.txt_Purchase_Price) = False Then

MsgBox "Please Enter Product Price", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.txt_Product_colour.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Product Colour", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product_Master")

Dim lr As Integer
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

Me.txt_id = StrConv(Me.txt_Product_Name.Value, vbProperCase) & "_" & StrConv(Me.txt_Product_colour.Value, vbProperCase)

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), Me.txt_id.Value) > 0 Then
MsgBox "This Product is already Available in product master", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = lr
sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_id.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 1).Value = StrConv(Me.txt_Product_Name.Value, vbProperCase)
sh.Range("D" & lr + 1).Value = StrConv(Me.txt_Product_colour.Value, vbProperCase)
sh.Range("E" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Purchase_Price.Value

Me.txt_id.Value = ""
Me.txt_Product_Name.Value = ""
Me.txt_Product_colour.Value = ""
Me.txt_Purchase_Price.Value = ""

MsgBox "Product has been added", vbInformation
Call show_data



End Sub


Sub show_data()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product_Master")

Dim lr As Integer
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
 
 If lr = 1 Then lr = 2
 
 
With Me.list_ProductMaster
    
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnWidths = "40,110,110,80,80"
    .RowSource = "Product_Master!A2:E" & lr
    
    
End With

End Sub


Private Sub btn_ProductMaster_Dlt_Click()

    list_ProductMaster.SetFocus
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product_Master")
    Dim lr As Integer
    
    
    lr = Me.txt_srno.Value
    MsgBox lr
    
      
        
        sh.Cells(lr + 1, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        
        Me.txt_srno.Value = ""
        Me.txt_id.Value = ""
        Me.txt_Product_Name.Value = ""
        Me.txt_Product_colour.Value = ""
        Me.txt_Purchase_Price.Value = ""
    
    
    MsgBox "Product has been Deleted", vbInformation
    
    
    Call show_data

End Sub


Private Sub btn_ProductMaster_Extract_Click()

Dim nwb As Workbook
Set nwb = Workbooks.Add

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master").UsedRange.Copy nwb.Sheets(1).Range("a1")


End Sub

Private Sub btn_ProductMaster_Updt_Click()

If Me.txt_Product_Name.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Product Name", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNumeric(Me.txt_Purchase_Price) = False Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Product Price", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.txt_Product_colour.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Product Colour", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product_Master")


Dim lr As Integer
lr = Me.txt_srno.Value

Me.txt_id = StrConv(Me.txt_Product_Name.Value, vbProperCase) & "_" & StrConv(Me.txt_Product_colour.Value, vbProperCase)

sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = lr
sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_id.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 1).Value = StrConv(Me.txt_Product_Name.Value, vbProperCase)
sh.Range("D" & lr + 1).Value = StrConv(Me.txt_Product_colour.Value, vbProperCase)
sh.Range("E" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Purchase_Price.Value

Me.txt_srno.Value = ""
Me.txt_id.Value = ""
Me.txt_Product_Name.Value = ""
Me.txt_Product_colour.Value = ""
Me.txt_Purchase_Price.Value = ""

MsgBox "Product has been Updated", vbInformation
Call show_data



End Sub


Private Sub list_ProductMaster_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    
    Me.txt_srno.Value = Me.list_ProductMaster.List(Me.list_ProductMaster.ListIndex, 0)
    Me.txt_id.Value = Me.list_ProductMaster.List(Me.list_ProductMaster.ListIndex, 1)
    Me.txt_Product_Name.Value = Me.list_ProductMaster.List(Me.list_ProductMaster.ListIndex, 2)
    Me.txt_Product_colour.Value = Me.list_ProductMaster.List(Me.list_ProductMaster.ListIndex, 3)
    Me.txt_Purchase_Price.Value = Me.list_ProductMaster.List(Me.list_ProductMaster.ListIndex, 4)

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    
    Call show_data
    
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Try `sh.Cells(lr+1, "A").EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Thanks...but it's Deleting all the rows.. :(

Comment: That can only delete one row, unless you're calling it multiple times.  It would help to show the rest of your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams Here's the code.

Comment: `lr` can't really be used as a way to determine what row should be deleted.  You need a different way to do that.

Comment: Pointer or any loop?

Comment: Each row needs a unique ID you can use to identify that specific record.  Using a row number is not reliable.  Plenty of examples out there: https://www.google.com/search?q=Excel+vba+userform+to+edit+data     Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336721/how-to-update-data-of-an-excel-sheet-in-a-userform-with-vba